# python: generate a 'diff' dictionary out of two nested dictionaries

Tags: python

I have written a function `diff` that takes two nested dictionaries and it computes a difference of their content (what is inside the list) returning a new dictionary. To better explain what I mean by difference here is an example of two input dictionaries:

```
dep={'cl1': {'to_do': ['bill', 'ann 46.0.1']},
     'cl2': {'to_do': ['ann 2.2.3']},
     'cl3': {'to_do': ['bill 2.4']}}

ins={'cl1': {'present': ['bill', 'ann 46.0.1', 'ann 2.2.3']},
     'cl2': {'present': ['ann 2.2.3','joy 6.9','matt 6.9']},
     'cl3': {'present': ['bill 2.4']}}
```

The `diff` function compares, for each key (`cl1` with `cl1`,`cl2` with `cl2` and so on...), the `present` list of `ins` with the `to_do` list of `dep`. If an item of the `present` list does not appear in the `to_do` list for a specific key than this item will be added to a list in the output dictionary. If the item found in the `present` is already in `to_do` than `None` will be added to the list. The function returns a dictionary having the same structure as the input dictionaries. Only the names appearing in the list are taken, i.e. no numbers after the names.

For instance the `diff` function applied to the case above will give:

```
out = diff(ins,dep)
out = {'cl1': {'to_uninstall': ['ann']},
       'cl2': {'to_uninstall': ['joy', 'matt']},
       'cl3': {'to_uninstall': [None]}}
```

Below is the function I am using:

```
def diff(installed, deploy):
    answer = {}
    #ls_uninst=[]
    for ki,vi in installed.iteritems():
        for kd, vd in deploy.iteritems():
            if ki == kd:
                for ki1, vi1 in vi.iteritems():
                    for kd1, vd1 in vd.iteritems():
                        ls_uninst = []
                        # check if the list is empty
                        if not vi1 :
                            answer[ki] = {}
                            answer[ki]['to_uninstall'] = [None]
                        # non empty list
                        else:
                            for i in vi1:
                                if i not in vd1:
                                    # this gives only the name of the package (not the version)
                                    ls_uninst.append(i.split()[0]) # use i only to get the full name
                                elif i in vd1:
                                    ls_uninst.append(None)
                                # Check if lists contains only None
                                if all(x is None for x in ls_uninst):
                                    answer[ki] = {}
                                    answer[ki]['to_uninstall'] = [None]
                                else: # If at least one package is found
                                    ls_final = [x for x in ls_uninst if x is not None]
                                    answer[ki] = {}
                                    answer[ki]['to_uninstall'] = ls_final
    return answer
```

It works but I guess this could improved..how? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start I'd change the way that you find `vd`. Instead of looping through the dictionary and checking the keys are the same, just do a lookup of the key.
This may raise a `KeyError`, and so you'll want to put a guard in for that.

However the rest of your code needs to change.
First if we have a look at your `for i in vi1` loop.
You have the comment `Check if lists contains only None`, but you're making that list?
Don't do this. Ever.
And so I would move the if and else out of that loop:

```
for i in vi1:
    if i not in vd1:
        ls_uninst.append(i.split()[0])
    elif i in vd1:
        ls_uninst.append(None)

if all(x is None for x in ls_uninst):
    answer[ki] = {}
    answer[ki]['to_uninstall'] = [None]
else:
    ls_final = [x for x in ls_uninst if x is not None]
    answer[ki] = {}
    answer[ki]['to_uninstall'] = ls_final
```

From this we can see that the for loop should probably be a comprehension, and I'm saying this now `[None]` is horrible, so I'm removing that from here.
Which would result in:

```
ls_uninst = [i.split()[0] for i in vi1 if i not in vd1]
```

After this, you should be able to see that if `not vi1` is true `not ls_uninst` is true too, and so you can merge these ifs.
Resulting in something like:

```
for kd1, vd1 in vd.iteritems():
    ls_uninst = [i.split()[0] for i in vi1 if i not in vd1]
    answer[ki] = {}
    if ls_uninst:
        answer[ki]['to_uninstall'] = ls_uninst
    else:
        answer[ki]['to_uninstall'] = [None]
```

The if can then become either a ternary, or you can use `or`. I think `or` is quite nice here.
But to be honest, you should just remove this if.

You should now have something that looks like:

```
def diff(installed, deploy):
    answer = {}
    for ki, vi in installed.iteritems():
        try:
            vd = deploy[ki]
        except KeyError:
            continue
        for ki1, vi1 in vi.iteritems():
            for kd1, vd1 in vd.iteritems():
                ls_uninst = [i.split()[0] for i in vi1 if i not in vd1]
                answer[ki] = {}
                answer[ki]['to_uninstall'] = ls_uninst or [None]
    return answer
```

This only uses the last `vi1` and `vd1` to create this list.
So you should use `itervalues` instead.
Also I'd use all of the values, not just the last.
This can be done by flattening `vi.itervalues`,
I'd do this by using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, but ultimately it's up to you.
I'd also change `vd1` to a set.
And all of this results in:

```
from itertools import chain
flatten = chain.from_iterable

def diff(installed, deploy):
    answer = {}
    for ki, vi in installed.iteritems():
        try:
            vd = deploy[ki]
        except KeyError:
            continue
        vi1 = flatten(vi.itervalues())
        vd1 = set(flatten(vd.itervalues()))
        ls_uninst = [i.split()[0] for i in vi1 if i not in vd1]
        answer[ki] = {}
        answer[ki]['to_uninstall'] = ls_uninst or [None]
    return answer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. It is much better now! I have few questions tough: 1) where in your code the diff function takes into account if the list is empty  (that would be my `if not vi1`) ? 2) what's the advantage of using the second version of your the diff function, i.e. `from intertools import ....`?

Comment: @diegus No problem! 1) I handle this the same way I do if none of them are in the other list, in both these cases `ls_uninst` will be empty, and so will go into the ternary. 2) I rephrased it, but add more values to cl1 say `'cl1': {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b']}`, your current method won't work correctly with that. As it'll ignore either 'a' or 'b'.